# Choose $\lambda$ in ridge regression so that $\beta$ shrinks to unit ball?

Tags: matrix-calculus

Recall ridge regression:
$$\beta(\lambda)=(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TY.$$

Is there an easy way I can find $\lambda$ so that the solution shrinks to the unit ball: $\beta^T(\lambda)\beta(\lambda)=1$?

My first thought is define $f(\lambda) = Y^TX(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-2}X^TY - 1$ then solve using Newton method, but I'd rather avoid iterative method if there's an analytic solution. If not, a little help with derivatives would be nice :)

I also thought about Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury, but I didn't get very far.

Comment: Found this: [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256807/how-exactly-to-compute-the-ridge-regression-constraint-given-the-penalty-paramet)